# How to get testcase status in @Aftertest in testng

Tags: testng

How i can get test case status in @AfterTest annotation of TestNg. I need to take some actions if test cases pass or fail in @AfterTest.

```
@AfterTest(alwaysRun=true)
public void teardown(ITestContext test) throws Exception {

  String testcase = test.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that `ITestContext` is global, and not specific to the test.  What you need is to have a Listener, and have it execute `OnTestFailure`

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners

Answer (score 0):

Listeners open a lot of possibilities, so you might want to look into that.

If you want a "quicker" solution, you can use `ITestResult.getStatus()`.

Here is an example of after method:

```
@AfterMethod
protected void afterMethod(ITestResult result, ITestContext testContext) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        //do something in case of fail
    } else {
        //do something else for success
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to pass your ITestResults in parameters!